# Can "also / as well / too" and "always" be in the same sentence?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

[In Longman dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/already)

> GRAMMAR: Word order • Already often comes at the end of a sentence:
>
> I knew that already.
>
> I was tired already.
>
> I have booked the tickets already.
>
> As well as at the end of a sentence, already can be used in the
>   following ways:
>
> • Already can come before a main verb:
>
> I already knew that.
>
> • Already comes after ‘be’ when it is the main verb:
>
> I was already tired.
>
> ✗Don’t say: I already was tired.
>
> • Already comes after the first auxiliary verb:
>
> I have already booked the tickets.
>
> ✗Don’t say: I already have booked the tickets.

[In Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/also?q=also)

> also / as well / too
>
> Also is more formal than as well and too, and it usually comes before
>   the main verb or after be: I went to New York last year, and I also
>   spent some time in Washington. In British English it is not usually
>   used at the end of a sentence. Too is much more common in spoken and
>   informal English. It is usually used at the end of a sentence:‘I’m
>   going home now.’ ‘I’ll come too.’. In British English as well is used
>   like too, but in North American English it sounds formal or
>   old-fashioned.

My question is that:

Can "*also / as well / too*" and "*always*" be in the same sentence?

Is it ok to say:

*I have already booked the flight, too*

*I have also already booked the flight.*

*I have already booked the flight, as well*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentences are correct and it is possible to use two adverbs in a sentence.

Remember that when you use words like *too*, *also*, and *as well*, you'll need to justify their use, which means having a prior idea to expand upon.

> I'm going to the mall. She is going [to the mall] **too**.
>
> I've gotten the birthday cake. I've **also** hung up the decorations.
>
> I've swept the floors and [I've] cleaned the sink **as well**.

If the action has been done, and it contains *already*, *too* and *as well* can be used to indicate that the same action has also been done by someone else:

> I've **already** been to that restaurant. I've **already** been [to that restaurant] **too**.
>
> I've **already** gone upstairs. I've **already** gone [upstairs] **as well**.

Answer (score 0):

> I've already booked the flight too
>
> I have already booked the flight, as well

- there, **too** and **as well** complement **flight**, and imply that you've booked something else in addition to the flight, perhaps the hotel.

> I have also already booked the flight.

There, you have done more than one thing already.  You have booked the flight already in addition to booking something else already.

Your sentences would be spoken only after an earlier statement about your having booked something.

So, in the first case (too, as well), you're referring to the *things* that have been booked already, and in the second case (also) you referring to the act of booking.  The difference arises from the *placement* of these words (too, as well, aslo) in the sentence.

Comment: The preceding action need not be a booking.  “I notified the consulate yesterday. I also have already booked the flight.”